# PHP 7.x Excel Class with UTF16 and function support (Alternative to PHPExcel)

Tags: php, excel, export-to-excel, import-from-excel

I used PHPExcel https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel, which has not been updated since 5 years or so and is not PHP 7.x compatible.

I use it to export and import data to webpages.

I need a tool which allows to include functions like `=LEN(200-A1)`.
Additionall complexity: UTF-16 Chars!

Export and import should not distroy them.

Its equalless which format at the end, if XML, XLS, XLSX, as long Excel opens it and can save it in the same forat, functions can be used (so no CSV file) with UTF-16 chars.

Does anyone know a good alternative with is updated frequently and working?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Try [EasyXLS](https://www.easyxls.com). It is regularly updated.

Comment: thx, I did find my new solution in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

I did find PHPSpreadsheet. Its nearly the same programmable logic which I used by PHPExcel before and its working up to php 7.1.9.
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Including good docu.